# What is the C# version of this ironpython code

Tags: c#, regex, ironpython

I need to write this IronPython code in C# (I couldn't find a similar C# library to match IronPython's re module):

```
for v in variables:
  replace = re.compile(v, re.IGNORECASE)...
  re.sub(v, str(self.SQLVariables[v.upper().replace("&","")]),script_content)...
```

In other words, what is the C# equivalent to the following expressions:

- re.compile(...)...
- re.sub(...)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question boils down to, *how do I use regular expressions in C#?*

The answer is the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class. To perform a replacement you need [`Regex.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). There is no need to explicitly compile the regex because that is done when you create the `Regex` instance.

---

The following [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) illustrates how to use the class:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much   " + 
                     "whitespace.";
      string pattern = "\\s+";
      string replacement = " ";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

      Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
      Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Original String: This is   text with   far  too   much   whitespace.
//       Replacement String: This is text with far too much whitespace.
```

Comment: No it is not. You can forget about `re.compile`. You don't need to use an equivalent with the .net regex class.

Comment: in other words the following should do it: foreach(string v in variables) { if( SQLVariables.ContainsKey(v.ToUpper().Replace("&",""))) script_content = Regex.Replace(v, (string)(SQLVariables[v.ToUpper().Replace("&","")]),script_content); }

Comment: No. Create an instance of the regex with `Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);` which includes the compile step. You then call `Replace()` on that instance.

Comment: I've added an example to the question. I think you should be able to work it out from here.